# stm32f051 Overwritten reserved

Tags: stm32, openocd, gdb

I think I may have overwritten the reserved bits when messing with GPIO on my board.
Now when I try to connect with OpenOCD it gives an error.

```
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v24 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.260948
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

Is there any way to erase the memory in flash without being able to connect to the board, or Have I bricked my board.

Comment: What do the "reserved bits" means in the context this processor? Can you provide a link to product manual that describes what you think you might have triggered?

Comment: Oddly enough, I've had the same problem about 1 minute ago - and it happens quite regularly in fact. In my case, it seems OpenOCD is unable to connect when the MCU isn't running (e.g. in stop mode, especially). What I do is I program an "always on" firmware doing stupid things like blinking the LED via the ST-LINK program (GUI or CLI, your choice). Then OpenOCD is able to connect. Alternatively, you can "Erase full chip" from ST-LINK's GUI. Oh, and the option bytes can be tweaked from there as well.

Comment: In regards to the reserved bits, I do not know what they do. The reference manual just states to keep them at reset value. I'm looking for a copy of the reference manual that I can link.

Comment: Here's an image of the page of the reference manual, which states the purpose of the bits I overwrote. http://imgur.com/jHeBQG0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix it.

First I launched OpenOCD with some special flags:

```
sudo openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg -c init -c "reset halt"
```

All while holding down reset for about half a second. Which causes it to connect in a halted state.

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2016-07-31-11:32)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To    override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The        results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v24 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.240792
Info : stm32f0x.cpu: hardware has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode:
```

I could then connect to OpenOCD with gdb and erase the flash and it connects without errors now.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the option bytes of a STM32 device to their factory settings with SEGGER's **J-Link Unlock STM32** tool. It is included in some SDKs but you can download it here :

https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink

You can also use **J-Flash** that is also included in J-Link to do a full erase.
Check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/unlocking-and-erasing-flash) too, it might help.

Comment: Unless SEGGER has changed their tools, these will only work with the SEGGER tools (J-Link variations, J-Trace, J-Flasher) and not with OpenOCD.